# How to use the getKeyStroke(String s) method?

Tags: java, key-bindings, keystroke

[Link to the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke-java.lang.String-)

I am trying to get an event when a key is released. I've tried formatting the String like it says to in the docs but it just makes that key unresponsive. Here is the working line of code:

```
getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), MOVE_DOWN);
```

Now I want to make it do something when I release the key, so attempting to follow the format from the doc, I've tried the following lines individually but they all make the key unresponsive:

```
1. getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN | pressed"), MOVE_DOWN);
2. getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN | released"), MOVE_DOWN);
3. getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN | true"), MOVE_DOWN);
4. getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN | false"), MOVE_DOWN);
5. getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN, true"), MOVE_DOWN);
6. getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("VK_DOWN, false"), MOVE_DOWN);
7. getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, false"), MOVE_DOWN);
```

You probably get the point... I have no idea how to format the String for this and have ran into a brick wall.

1. How am I supposed to format the String for this?
2. I saw that there are other methods, would it be better for me to use one of those instead, and how?

I feel like getKeyStroke(char keyChar, boolean onKeyRelease) is my best bet, but it says it's deprecated so should I totally avoid using that one?

Comment: That's a factory method, not a constructor.

Comment: Whoops, I'll edit that, knew I messed up somewhere

Comment: I prefer to use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int, int, boolean);` which, in my experience, is more reliable then sting parsing.  For example `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true);` sets up a key stroke for down, no modifiers on key release

Comment: @MadProgrammer I saw that the second parameter for that method is a modifier? That's what was scaring me away from that one, but how would you use the modifiers for that? The documentation says "a bitwise-ored combination of any modifiers" so would `1` be `SHIFT_DOWN_MASK`, and so on?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift would be `KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK` or something similar - I never rely on magic numbers and rely or named consents ;) - Demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46985936/using-keybinding-and-action-map-in-java-for-shortcut-keys-for-buttons/46986203#46986203)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke-java.lang.String-) seems to be pretty clear.  We can correct your example with the following:

```
getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed DOWN"), MOVE_DOWN);
getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released DOWN"), MOVE_DOWN);
```

Note that the following is equivalent to `"pressed DOWN"`:

```
getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), MOVE_DOWN);
```

Comment: Wow I was skipping straight to the second section and placing it in the wrong order this worked immediately thank you!