# c# GetKeystroke() name does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

I am learning from the book 'C# 9 and .NET 5'. In the second chapter, the author uses the function GetKeystroke(), which does not appear to be defined with the libraries imported. I was unable to find online documentation for this function in C#. The most similar SO question I could find on SO referred to java [How to use the getKeyStroke(String s) method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072234/how-to-use-the-getkeystrokestring-s-method)

My question is then:

1. is there a library where I can import this function?
2. how would I be able to find out (1) for myself in the future?

My current reasoning is that, as GetKeystroke is in Title case rather than camelcase, this shouldn't be a function the author has locally defined, but isntead is something he is importing. However, there was no definition found in Visual Studio Code, and nothing I could find on the internet.

Thank you very much -  and apologies that this question probably has a very simple answer I am missing!

Comment: I haven't read this book, so just guessing... Is it perhaps just an example/hypothetical function he describes? Or perhaps one he wrote earlier in the chapter? Looking at what seems to be the [accompanying GitHub repo](https://github.com/markjprice/cs9dotnet5) there's no mention of that method.

Comment: ah ok! thank you. that makes sense as it hadn't been previously mentioned. I thought that might be the case, but also thought I might have not installed something properly

Answer (score 1):

The author defined the method. You can use " Console.ReadKey() ".
Example:

```
char userChoice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Here you have the official Microsoft documentation:
[Console.ReadKey() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-6.0)

The author probably created his own method instead of using Console.ReadKey() :

```
static void GetKeyStroke(){ Console.ReadKey().KeyChar }
char userChoice = GetKeyStroke();
```